# "Dizer-se-ia" pode estar de acordo com a norma padrão?

Tags: conjugações

Normalmente, a mesóclise é feita removendo-se o sufixo do futuro ou futuro do pretérito e pondo o pronome entre o que sobrou do verbo e esse sufixo. No caso de verbos com futuros irregulares, como "fazer" ou "dizer", a irregularidade é mantida, o que leva a formas como "fá-lo-ei" e "di-lo-ia".

A página [conjugação](http://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-dizer/), no entanto, além das formas citadas acima, também lista construções a partir de versões regulares do futuro desses verbos no que eles chamam de "conjugação pronominal reflexa", levando a formas como "fazer-se-ia" e "dizer-me-ia". Quando li isso, tive a impressão de que essas formas não estavam de acordo com a norma padrão, mas não pude encontrar referências satisfatórias a respeito; o próprio Evanildo Bechara em sua gramática não explica em profundidade como é feita a mesóclise.

Existe alguma referência completa que permita rechaçar essa conjugação? Ou o que está escrito na página faz, de fato, sentido?

Comment: O meu word rejeita "eu fazer-me-ei" e "eu dizer-me-ei" e aceita "eu far-me-ei" e "eu dir-me-ei."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ciberúvidas diz que é *far-me-ei* e não *fazer-me-ei*.](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-forma-irregular-desfar-se-iam-verbo-desfazer-se/31796) Do mesmo modo, ***dir-me-ei*** e ***trar-me-ei*** e não *dizer-me-ei* ou *trazer-me-ei*; e do mesmo modo para o condicional/futuro do pretérito. O Word instalado no meu computador também segue esta regra. E eu vou lançar o meu chapéu ao ringue, e dizer que foi a [conjugação.com](http://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-fazer/) quem se enganou com o *fazer-me-ei, dizer-me-ei*, etc. (Atualização: A [conjugação.com](http://www.conjugacao.com.br/verbo-fazer/) enganou-se mesmo, e já corrigiu o engano: já lá não nenhum desses *fazer-me-ei*, etc.; deixo o resto da resposta inalterada para memória.)

*Conjugação.com* prescreve a forma ***fazer-me-ei***, etc. apenas para a conjugação pronominal reflexa e não para as restantes conjugações pronominais: *eu fazer-me-ei, ele fazer-se-á*, mas *eu far-lhe-ei, ele far-me-á*. Então
de acordo com as regras de conjugação universalmente aceites, já que não há desacordo quanto às conjugações não reflexas, e as regras de colocação pronominal, teríamos o seguinte:

> Eu **farei** um favor ao Pedro / Eu **far-lhe-ei** um favor / Eu **sempre lhe farei** um favor.

Mas se eu continuar a ser o autor do favor, e passar também a ser o seu beneficiário , de acordo com *conjugação.com* passaríamos a ter:

> Eu **farei** um favor a mim mesmo / Eu **fazer-me-ei** um favor / Eu **sempre me fazerei/farei (?)**  um favor.

*Eu **fazer-me-ei*** e *eu sempre **me fazerei***/***farei*** são ambas conjugações pronominais reflexas. Seria muito estranho que a forma do verbo se alterasse de *fazer-me-ei* para *me farei* só por se passar da mesóclise para a próclise, o que sugere *me fazerei*. Mas seria igualmente estranho que se passasse de *me fazerei* para *farei (...) a mim* só por passarmos do pronome *me* para *a mim* (*fazer a mim* não é conjugação pronominal), quando todas as frases significam exatamente o mesmo.

De acordo com o Ciberdúvidas não há nenhuma destas complicações:

> Eu **farei** um favor a mim mesmo / Eu **far-me-ei** um favor / Eu **sempre me farei**  um favor.

O meu palpite é que alguém no *conjugação.com* escreveu um algoritmo que funciona na maioria dos verbos e não reparou que não funcionava para *fazer, dizer e trazer*. Mandei-lhes um mail. Dir-vos-ei quando receber resposta. (Continuação da atualização: nunca me responderam.)

Comment: Obrigado pela referência. Concordo plenamente com o que disse; eu inclusive tinha já passado pela página do Ciberdúvidas antes. Seria legal se conseguíssimos encontrar uma referência em algum livro que cubra explicitamente esse caso...

Comment: @Arthur Eu tenho esperança que me respondam do conjugação.com e que isso arrume a questão.

Comment: @Arthur, a conjugação.com corrigiu o engano.

Answer (score 0):

E a eufonia não conta? Não é.mais estético dizer-se: " eu me  farei a mim..." (aqui a redundância de estilo, usual entre os clássicos) pois, far-me-ei a mim mesmo a indagação  do filósofo. Para melhor reflexão. O pronome reto deve atrair a próclise

Comment: Fernando, bem-vindo ao site. Eu não compreendi se tentaste responder à pergunta (não me parece, já que a pergunta não é sobre "me farei" versus "far-me-ei") ou se queres fazer uma pergunta adicional. Neste caso, deves abrir uma thread nova: clica em [Ask Question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) (neste link ou no canto superior direito da página) e segue as instruções.